# How to represent the contour of a 2d object from an image in form of a signal using pywavelets

Tags: python, wavelet-transform, pywavelets

Im trying to apply a db wavelet transformation to an image and represent the contour in form of a signal in python. Im not sure what the steps are tho. I have already detected the contour. 
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!